# How to add a row to Eloquent Model?

Tags: php, laravel

I was using Eloquent Model to `Form::select` as follow:

```
Category::lists('name','id')
```

And now, I want to add option `ALL` to select all categories.

How to add this ?
for Example:

```
<select>
<option>All</option>
<option value='1'>cat1</option>
<option value='2'>cat2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple

```
$category = Category::lists('name', 'id');

Form::select("cat",array(""=>"ALL")+$category);
```

Comment: Thanks much. Problem with array(""=>"all")+$category